# RuntimeException: Uncompilable code - 'void' type not allowed here

Tags: java

estoy intentando hacer un pequeño programa en el cual introduciendo unos parametros me hagan varias funciones, como darme el IMC de la persona, si es mayor de edad, hacer un DNI aleatorio....

El problema es que en la clase Persona que defino esos métodos los declaro con public void y lo guardo y no me da ningún problema. Tengo creado una clase con el main, y puedo instanciar la clase, llamar a métodos sobrecargados como toString pero cuando hago la llamada al método IMC o el de generar DNI me salta este error.

esto está declarado en la clase persona

```java
public void calcularIMC(){
    
    double resultado = this.peso/Math.pow(this.altura,2);
    
    if(resultado <18.5){
        System.out.println(" El peso es inferior al peso normal");
    }else if(resultado >18.5 && resultado<24.9)   { 
        System.out.println("Estás en el peso ideal");
    }else if(resultado > 25.0 && resultado <29.9){
        System.out.println("Tienes sobrepeso");
    } else System.out.println("Tienes obesidad");
}
```

y esto en la clase main, ya instanciada la clase

```java
System.out.println(pe1.calcularIMC());
```

He probado varias formas, pero sigue dando el mismo error.

Gracias y un saludo,

Answer (score 1):

El método `System.out.println(...)` imprime en pantalla lo que le pases. Pero **debes** pasarle algo. Tu método `calcularIMC()` no devuelve **nada**, es lo que significa `void`. Lo que has hecho es que sea el propio método `calcularIMC` el que imprima un valor, así que tienes dos opciones:

Llama al método sin esperar que devuelva nada, por lo que no necesitas usar `System.out.println` en el método `main`:

```java
public static void main (String ...args) {
   // ...
   pe1.calcularIMC();
}
```

Modificar el método para que devuelva el texto, en lugar de imprimirla:

```java
public String calcularIMC(){
 
    double resultado = this.peso/Math.pow(this.altura,2);
    
    if(resultado <18.5){
        return "El peso es inferior al peso normal";
    }else if(resultado >18.5 && resultado<24.9)   { 
        return "Estás en el peso ideal";
    }else if(resultado > 25.0 && resultado <29.9){
        return "Tienes sobrepeso";
    }
    return "Tienes obesidad";
}
```